# RedisTimeSeries TS.RANGE returns timestamps in the past

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I have the following RedisTimeSeries key:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ts.info ts_raw_l:TSLA
 1) totalSamples
 2) (integer) 771
 3) memoryUsage
 4) (integer) 8416
 5) firstTimestamp
 6) (integer) 1546405200000
 7) lastTimestamp
 8) (integer) 1642741200000
 9) retentionTime
10) (integer) 0
11) chunkCount
12) (integer) 2
13) chunkSize
14) (integer) 4096
15) chunkType
16) compressed
17) duplicatePolicy
18) (nil)
19) labels
20) (empty array)
21) sourceKey
22) (nil)
23) rules
24) 1) 1) "ts_agg_y_l:TSLA"
       2) (integer) 31556952000
       3) MIN
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I have a range query where `fromTimestamp` and `toTimestamp` represent a time period of 5 business days.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ts.range ts_raw_l:TSLA 1641790800000 1642222799000
1) 1) (integer) 1641790800000
   2) 980
2) 1) (integer) 1641877200000
   2) 1038.82
3) 1) (integer) 1641963600000
   2) 1072.5901
4) 1) (integer) 1642050000000
   2) 1026.5391
5) 1) (integer) 1642136400000
   2) 1013.3788
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I apply a `min` aggregation filter to this range with a `timeBucket` value of 5 days and `align` it with `fromTimestamp`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.RANGE ts_raw_l:TSLA 1641790800000 1642222799000 ALIGN 1641790800000 AGGREGATION min 432000000
1) 1) (integer) 1641600000000
   2) 980
2) 1) (integer) 1642032000000
   2) 1013.3788
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I would expect one result, `980` and I would expect the timestamp of that result to be within the `fromTimestamp` and `toTimestamp` ranges provided in the query.

Why do I get two results?  And, why is `980` returned with a timestamp that is earlier than `fromTimestamp`?

Redis/module versions:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MODULE LIST
1) 1) "name"
   2) "bf"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20206
2) 1) "name"
   2) "ai"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10205
3) 1) "name"
   2) "timeseries"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10410
4) 1) "name"
   2) "rg"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10008
5) 1) "name"
   2) "graph"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20411
6) 1) "name"
   2) "ReJSON"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20004
7) 1) "name"
   2) "search"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 20205
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: can you provide the RedisTimeSeries version?

Comment: @Danni I updated the original question to include the redis and module versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is supported in `master` and 1.6 (or newer) versions. Make sure you use a newer version of RedisTimeSeries.